# Import data vector from julia to R using RCall

Tags: r, julia, rcall

Assume I have a Julia data array like this:

```
Any[Any[1,missing], Any[2,5], Any[3,6]]
```

I want to import it to R using RCall so I have an output equivalent to this:

```
data <- cbind(c(1,NA), c(2,5), c(3,6))
```

Note: the length of data is dynamic and it may be not 3!

could anyone help me how can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just interpolate a matrix into R:

```
a = [ 1    2  3
   missing 5  6 ]
R"data <- $a"
```

To reorgnize your "array of array" into a matrix, you need to concat them

```
b = Any[Any[1,missing], Any[2,5], Any[3,6]]
a = hcat(b...)
R"data <- $a"
```